# Dynamic Plots Based on One or More Dropdown Values

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to make multiple dynamic plots (one does not know how many plots will output) based on one or more selected dropdown value(s) (`species` in this case).

I did succeed making plots based on the dropdown. For instance, two plots are displayed if a user selected two values/species from the dropdown list, one plot is displayed if one value/species is selected.

Although the number of plots match the number of dropdown values, the plots show a duplicate if two or more dropdown values/species are selected (it only works if exactly one value is selected). Any advice would be of great help.

The below code uses the iris dataset in R.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLUov.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGSqe.png)

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)

species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "ddPCR"),
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General Overview", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        uiOutput("species_dropdown"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$species_dropdown <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      "var1",
      "Species:",
      choices = species,
      options = pickerOptions(
        actionsBox = T,
        header = "Close",
        liveSearch = T
      ),
      multiple = T
    )
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% 
      filter(Species %in% input$var1)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$var1)
    filtered_data()
  })
  
  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$var1)
    
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:length(input$var1), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })
    
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  for (i in 1:length(species)) {
    local({
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")

      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = paste(input$var1, sep = ""), x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") 
      })
    })
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments in [this](https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/) app on line 34:

> Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
> of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
> of when the expression is evaluated.

So you need to assign i to a local variable otherwise it will be the same for all renderPlots, hence why your plots are identical. Also, your title should be changed to index the inputs, otherwise only the first element is used to the title argument because paste will return a list when it is passed a list, while title requires just one value.

Full app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)

species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "ddPCR"),
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General Overview", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        uiOutput("species_dropdown"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$species_dropdown <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      "var1",
      "Species:",
      choices = species,
      options = pickerOptions(
        actionsBox = T,
        header = "Close",
        liveSearch = T
      ),
      multiple = T
    )
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% 
      filter(Species %in% input$var1)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$var1)
    filtered_data()
  })
  
  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$var1)
    
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:length(input$var1), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })
    
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  for (i in 1:length(species)) {
    
    local({
      my_i <- i #crucial
      
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="") # use my_i instead of i
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        
        ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = paste(input$var1[my_i], sep = ""), x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") # title needs input$var1 indexed as paste will return a list otherwise, in which case only a first element gets used for the title hence all titles are identical
        

      })
    })
  }
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, but the plots I see are identical when I choose two or more values. However, I did see the species names get changed properly. It's strange how my plots look different from your screenshot.

Comment: I found the solution: Use ```iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$var[my_i]``` directly inside ggplot() within ```local({})``` instead using filtered_data() in reactive