# Dynamic Plots Based on One or More Dropdown Values 2

Tags: shiny

This question is related to one I asked here: [Dynamic Plots Based on One or More Dropdown Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70599776/dynamic-plots-based-on-one-or-more-dropdown-values). Although I got an answer from Mr.Rlover, the resulting plots do not look the same. If I choose two or more plots, it seems that the data is being added on and this is reflected exactly in the plots. I wonder how one would separate data based on different `species`.

[one species selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lckzN.png)
[two or more species selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fteG.png)

Below was my original question:

I am trying to make multiple dynamic plots (one does not know how many plots will output) based on one or more selected dropdown value(s) (species in this case).

I did succeed making plots based on the dropdown. For instance, two plots are displayed if a user selected two values/species from the dropdown list, one plot is displayed if one value/species is selected.

Although the number of plots match the number of dropdown values, the plots show a duplicate if two or more dropdown values/species are selected (it only works if exactly one value is selected). Any advice would be of great help.

The below code uses the iris dataset in R.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinydashboard)


species = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General Overview", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        uiOutput("species_dropdown"),
        # DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$species_dropdown <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      "var1",
      "Species:",
      choices = species,
      options = pickerOptions(
        actionsBox = T,
        header = "Close",
        liveSearch = T
      ),
      multiple = T
    )
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    iris %>% 
      filter(Species %in% input$var1) # I think is causing the problem
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$var1)
    filtered_data()
  })
  
  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$var1)
    
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:length(input$var1), function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })
    
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  for (i in 1:length(species)) {
    
    local({
      my_i <- i #crucial
      
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="") # use my_i instead of i
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        
        ggplot(filtered_data(), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = paste(input$var1[my_i], sep = ""), x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") # title needs input$var1 indexed as paste will return a list otherwise, in which case only a first element gets used for the title hence all titles are identical
        
        
      })
    })
  }
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$var1)` only one dataset was generated. We need one per number of Species.

Instead we create a list with each corresponding plot:

```
    filtered_data <- reactive({
        map(input$var1, ~
        iris %>% 
            filter(Species == .x)) 
    })
```

and subset it with `filtered_data()[[index]]`

Full app

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General Overview", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        uiOutput("species_dropdown"),
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
  output$species_dropdown <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      "var1",
      "Species:",
      choices = species,
      options = pickerOptions(
        actionsBox = T,
        header = "Close",
        liveSearch = T
      ),
      multiple = T
    )
  })

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    map(input$var1, ~
    iris %>%
      filter(Species == .x)) %>%
      set_names(input$var1) 
  })


  #Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$var1)

    plot_output_list <- lapply(input$var1, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot_", i, sep = "")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })

    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  observeEvent(filtered_data(), {
  iwalk(filtered_data(), ~{
    output[[paste0("plot_",.y)]] <<- renderPlot({
      ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
        geom_point() +
        labs(title = .y, x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width")
    })
  })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$var1[my_i])` directly inside `local({})` was the key instead of using:

```
   filtered_data <- reactive({
     iris %>% 
       filter(Species %in% input$var1)
   })
```

```r
  for (i in 1:length(species)) {
    local({
      my_i <- i 
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="") 
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(iris %>% filter(Species %in% input$var1[my_i]), aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = paste(input$var1[my_i], sep = ""), x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") 
      })
    })
  }
```